# Safari Browser: Not able to click file type element on safari browser using Selenium

Tags: jquery, macos, selenium, safari

Not able to click below element on **safari** browser using *Selenium*-

```html
<input type="file" multiple file-input="file" id="fileTest" on-change="readFile()" title="Click here to add files">
```

Comment: are you using Java, C#, or python?

Comment: Using java with selenium driver

Comment: @rajatsharma do you wants to upload file ?

Comment: Yes upload a file in Safari btowser.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my syntax (I don't write Java much) but if you simply want to click on the 'Choose Files' button, wouldn't it simply be:

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.findElement(By.id("fileTest")).click();
```

Now if you actually wanted to automate the file upload: 1) you would need to know the path of the file, and 2) you would use .sendkeys()

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.findElement(By.id("fileTest")).sendKeys("\path\to\file\you\want\to\upload");
```

Comment: With Safari you have to make the ‘allow remote automation’ option available in the developer menu

Comment: Did that fix it?

Comment: Yes ‘allow remote automation’ option is already enabled. Seems this issue with the browser support since not able to click the same element using jquery.